# I want change my image in android

Tags: android, imageview

i want to change my image, if i have this code:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

that code works, but i want save `R.drawable.my_image` in one variable
let's say `listofimage` , it because i must change the name of image file
let's say i have "my_image", "my_image1", "my_image2"

i try to change the code like this

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
string listofimage="";

if(result1.equals("my_image")){
listofimage="R.drawable.my_image";
} else if (result1.equals("my_image1")) {
listofimage="R.drawable.my_image1";
}else if (result1.equals("my_image2")) {
listofimage="R.drawable.my_image2";
}
img.setImageResource(listofimage);
```

but that code didn't work. can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide more information. Maybe you can try use local variable, by adding "int" before "listofimage"?

Comment: What you want to save... the image path? the image name? Can you be a little more specific on your request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code you could  do like this:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

if(result1.equals("my_image")){
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
} else if (result1.equals("my_image1")) {
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image1);

}else if (result1.equals("my_image2")) {
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code contains three compilation errors:

1. `String` with lowercase "s"
2. `R.drawable.my_image` is of type `int`
3. `setImageResource` expects `int` as its parameter

Solution is to replace "string" with "int" in your code to look like this:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
int listofimage=R.drawable.my_image;
img.setImageResource(listofimage);
```

Comment: i try to use 
    Integer.parseInt(listofimage);

i didn't see error in eclipse but when i run the app, it force close